# How to make the code shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Sorry for my English. I am trying to make a website, where you click on a picture of a president and jQuery changes background of the website. My code is really big and clumsy. Is there a way to use loops or something to shorten it? Thanks in advance.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#truman').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/trumanBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
  $('#kennedy').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/kennedyBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
  $('#eisenhower').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/eisenhowerBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
  $('#johnson').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/johnsonBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
  $('#nixon').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/nixonBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
  $('#ford').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/fordBg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
    $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
    $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
    $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');
  });
});
```

Comment: You could start by removing all the vendor-prefixed versions of `background-size`, which are not necessary and have not been for a while. In fact, I don't think there was ever a `-o-background-size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give them all the same class - here "president"  and do

```
$(function(){
  $('.president').click(function(){
    $('body').css('background', 'url(img/bg/'+this.id+'Bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed');
    $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover'); 
    .....
```

The alternative is to change the image -

```
$(function(){
  $('.president').click(function(){
    $("body").css('background-image','url(img/bg/'+this.id+'Bg.jpg)'); 
  });  
});
```

Another alternative is to just change the class but watch it if you have more than one class on the body tag

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support, but this is the solution what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I had wrapped your common thing in a function. You can do more stuff when you want to add more styles.

This will be most helpful when you are not having same class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#truman').click(function(){
       applyStyles("truman");
      });
      $('#kennedy').click(function(){
       applyStyles("kennedy");
      });
      $('#eisenhower').click(function(){
        applyStyles("eisenhower");
      });
      $('#johnson').click(function(){
        applyStyles("johnson");
      });
      $('#nixon').click(function(){
        applyStyles("nixon");
      });
      $('#ford').click(function(){
        applyStyles("ford");
      });
    });

function applyStyles(name) {
        var url = 'url(img/bg/'+name+'Bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed';
        $('body').css('background', url);
        $('body').css('-webkit-background-size', 'cover');
        $('body').css('-moz-background-size',    'cover');
        $('body').css('-o-background-size',      'cover');
        $('body').css('background-size',         'cover');

}
```

Comment: That is still very repetitive

Comment: @mplungjan thats the reason I mentioned its useful only when there are different class names. Here the OP did not post the html part which would have been easier to minimize the repetitive part

Comment: There is no need for HTML - he is changing the body tag only

Comment: HTML part needed to handle click event

Comment: Click handler on whatever the president was

Comment: yeah thats what I mean what commonality do they posses. Are they in a list, table or div. I didnt assume any of such things that other answers assumed here thats why you feel its still repetitive

Comment: No, not at all. This is repetitive compared to a single click handler for all `$('#truman').click(function(){
       applyStyles("truman");
      });
      $('#kennedy').click(function(){
       applyStyles("kennedy");
      });
      $('#eisenhower').click(function(){
        applyStyles("eisenhower");
      });
      $('#johnson').click(function(){
        applyStyles("johnson");
      });
      $('#nixon').click(function(){
        applyStyles("nixon");
      });
      $('#ford').click(function(){
        applyStyles("ford");
      });`

Answer (score 1):

Posting my comment as an answer, I'd go this way:

In the HTML, i'd wrap the presidents in a div, and use the same class name in CSS as the DIV id, so it'd be shorter to write in JS.

```js
function clearPreviousPresidentClass() {
  $('body').removeClass('nixon truman kennedy');
}

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#presidents').click(function(event) {
    clearPreviousPresidentClass();
    $('body').addClass(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.truman {
  background-color: red;
}

.nixon {
  background-color: blue;
}

.kennedy {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="presidents">
    <div id="nixon">Nixon</div>
    <div id="truman">Truman</div>
    <div id="kennedy">Kennedy</div>
  </div>
</body>
```